# Difference between page and this object in JSP

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have declared a variable in a jsp page as

```
<%! int i=20; %>
```

And tried to print in via

```
<%=this.i %>
```

Which seems to work fine. But since implicit page object of a jsp page is pointing to "this" as

```
final java.lang.Object page = this;
```

Why is

```
<%=page.i %>
```

No possible? (it gives out a error at compile time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of page is `Object`, so it does not know of the attributes in the generated code of your JSP page.